# Journey Builder - Looping Alternatives

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Since join activities in Journey Builder don't allow you to loop back onto the same path (it actually seems to break everything when you even attempt it using the new UI), I was wondering what people's favourite alternative is?

The only real solution I can think of involves taking the original contact entry date, and after a certain amount of time has passed (the length of the Journey), a query will re-append them into the source data extension. The query would also  apply the date it re-added them, so that you could reuse that query to create the infinite loop.

If you have any better ideas I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the [Event Administration](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/journey_builder_administration/event_administration/) feature to chose the data sources from what is configured in Contact Builder, define how often to inject new subscribers, and what criteria a subscriber has to meet to enter the Journey.

You can actually schedule the periodicity as shown here.

[image]

> Use this step to determine when and how often Journey Builder checks
>   the event source for new records to inject into the Interaction.
>
> If contacts are injected into the Interaction via API or using
>   Automation Studio, select the top option. Setting an entry schedule
>   here is not necessary. If contacts should be injected according to a
>   schedule, select the bottom option.
>
> Step 5: Set Entry Schedule
>
> Set the date, time zone, and repetition schedule. The default Repeat
>   setting is None, which means the entry event runs only on the
>   scheduled date and time.
>
> The Start Date set here is used by the entry event that is being
>   configured. This schedule dictates when Journey Builder checks the
>   event source for new records. The schedule set here does not inject
>   contacts into the Interaction unless the Interaction has been
>   activated.
>
> In cases where the schedule set here begins prior to the Interaction's
>   activation, Journey Builder only injects contacts that are newly added
>   to the event source after Interaction activation.

Comment: Ah very good explanation. As some of my use cases will involve Journey's that need Salesforce events it wouldn't cover all of these, but for others thats a great option that I have been overlooking.

Comment: Okay, great! If this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it as the Answer for others benefit as well.

Comment: Sorry wanted to keep it open to see if other people had their own suggestions to share - which they are still free to do!

Answer (score 0):

This is where the Journey Contact Entry and Re-Entry conditions come into play (using an *Audience* Entry Source)

If you would like your entrants to qualify for the Journey again:

- Ensure you have an entry condition which allows them to qualify for re-entry again (such as "Status" = 1, or a condition which doesn't change throughout the Journey) and no date based filtering ("Datecreated" = "today - 1 day")
- Contact Re-Entry (under Journey Settings) is set to "Re-entry anytime"

Also, as a side note, when testing Journeys, I find it helpful to set Contact Re-Entry to "Re-entry anytime", allowing those same Contacts to re-enter the Journey on the next Draft without having to fully exit the Journey first (due to the default 1 day Wait Activity before Exit).  This can only be set before the first Activation of the Journey though.